# Configure Vert.x proxy for Firefox

Tags: firefox, groovy, vert.x

I would like to run a verticle at port 8080 on the localhost so that when I configure Firefox to use `http://localhost:8080` as proxy, it will connect to the verticle and I should be able to get the URL that was requested.

In other words, whatever URL I type in my address bar(say www.google.com), that should be available in the verticle. My ultimate aim is to get the html at the URL, inject some script of my own and serve it up to the user.

Currently when I run a server at 8080 Firefox simply responds that Server didn't respond.

Also I am unable to `println` anything when I type a URL(like google.com) which seems to suggest a connection was never made. Instead when I type localhost:8080 I get a proper response as well as the absoluteURL.

Comment: have you set your firefox proxy address in Perferences->Network->Connection Settings?

Comment: Yes, I have set it to localhost 8080 where the proxy is deployed.

Comment: I guess your code isn't right then...

Comment: I am using the code similar to https://github.com/vert-x/vertx-examples/blob/master/src/raw/groovy/proxy/Server.groovy to create a server. Except for localhost:8080 it doesn't respond to any other requests.

Comment: Using that code, and firefox with the proxy set up and the _"Use this proxy for all protocols"_ checkbox checked, it all works as expected...

Comment: So if you type google.com in your address bar, are you able to obtain the url in your verticle? Which property did you use to access the URL? Could you share the code? For me nothing inside the verticle gets printed as if it was never executed. Also I did check the "Use this proxy for all protocols" box but nothing happened.

Comment: I ran the proxy example you linked to, Set the _"HTTP Proxy"_ to `localhost`, the port to `8282` and checked `Use this proxy server for all protocols`. I then typed `www.google.com` into the address bar, and got `server-data-chunk-0server-data-chunk-1server-data-chunk-2server-data-chunk-3server-data-chunk-4server-data-chunk-5server-data-chunk-6server-data-chunk-7server-data-chunk-8server-data-chunk-9` as the output to the page

Comment: Yes. I configured everything on a different computer and now it seems to work (don't know what I did wrong on the earlier computer; I deserved the downvote I think). Thank you very much for your patience with me.

Comment: No worries :-)  Glad you got it working!  Maybe a caching issue?  I've added an answer with steps to follow (and this extra cache bit on the end)  Good luck! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odd..  If you run the proxy example in the vertx-examples repository:

https://github.com/vert-x/vertx-examples/blob/master/src/raw/groovy/proxy/Server.groovy

That starts the proxy on port `8282`.  If you then go into the Firefox preferences:

> Preferences -> Network -> Connection Settings

And set the `HTTP Proxy` to `localhost`, the `port` to `8282` and check the checkbox `Use this proxy server for all protocols`

Then typing `google.com` into the address bar should show logging in the terminal window, and the browser should display:

```
server-data-chunk-0server-data-chunk-1server-data-chunk-2server-data-chunk-3ser‌​ver-data-chunk-4server-data-chunk-5server-data-chunk-6server-data-chunk-7server-d‌​ata-chunk-8server-data-chunk-9
```

Maybe it's cached something in the browser?  Try clearing the caches before navigating to google?